# implement ordinal regression in Theano

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, theano

I want to implement [ordinal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) in Theano. But I've no idea how to implement the middle part: threshold definition and usage.

For example(simply say):

```
X = T.matrix('X', dtype='float32') # Feature matrix
y = T.vector('y', dtype='int32') # labels

w = T.vector('w', dtype='float32')
threshold = T.vector('threshold', dtype='float32')

p = T.nnet.sigmoid(threshold - T.dot(X, w))
p_y_x = theano.ifelse.ifelse(T.eq(y, 0), p[y], (p[y] - p[y-1]))

loss = -T.sum(T.log(p_y_x))
```

I notice there would be something wrong with the definition of `p_y_x` as well as `p`. But I've no idea how to modify it. Can anyone help?